# Spring Boot Oauth2 doesn't work with form login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I tried to make an Oauth2 server. It works fine, until I turn on form login. When I do, it redirects me to the login form, even though my request contains the access token.

Authorization server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("isAnonymous() || hasRole('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')").checkTokenAccess("hasRole('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("my-trusted-client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials,", "password", "authorization_code")
                .authorities("USER")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600)
                .secret("secret")
                .autoApprove(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

WebSecurity:

```
@Configuration
public class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .formLogin()
                .and()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .anonymous().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

Resource server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/me").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

User info:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value ="/me", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> user(Principal principal) {
        HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("username", principal.getName());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
    }

}
```

The app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class Security1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Security1Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void authenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder, UserService userService) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userService);
    }

}
```

I also have a user service that returns UserDetails.

When I try it from browser, it works fine. I can login and then acces the restricted /me endpoint. But if I get an access token from the token endpoint and try to use it to access /me I get redirected to the login form. If I remove the .formLogin(), then the token works, but on the website I have to login in a popup alert window, which is not very nice.

Comment: And of course my client doesnt work like this. When it reuqest the user-infio, it gets the login form.

Comment: I am sure you do not need the annotation _@EnableAuthorizationServer_ below the _@SpringBootApplication_ annotation

Comment: You are not annotating the security with _@EnableWebSecurity_ annotation. Have a look at http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html . you might find the answer

Comment: @kimy82 Why wouldn't I? Without it I would not have token and authorize endpoints, and I need those so that my client service can interact.

Enabling web security does not change a thing. I read this tutorial page, but it didn't help.

I might have not been clean but my goal is:
- I call my client service
- It sees that I am unauthenticated, redirects me to the ouath2 service
- I log in on a custom html page with a form
- It redirects me to the client with a code and i get authenticated with that

It works perfectly without the formLogin but It doesnt work with formLogin.

Comment: And the reason it doesn't work with the formLogin() is because altough my client sends an access token, the oauth2 service redirects it to the login form.